# Is there a good way to pass "array addresses" to a method?

Tags: ruby, store

How can I refactor the following? I have some values stored in my YAML file as nested arrays, but I want to pull all my transactions into two get and set methods. This works, but is obviously limited and bulky. It feels wrong.

```
module Persistance
  @store = YAML::Store.new('store.yml')

  def self.get_transaction(key)
    @store.transaction { @store[key] }
  end

  def self.get_nested_transaction(key, sub)
    @store.transaction { @store[key][sub] }
  end
end
```

Bonus credit: I also have an additional method for incrementing values in my YAML file. Is there a further way to refactor this code? Does it make sense to just pass blocks to a single database accessing method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I remember thinking about this when I was practicing PStore a little while ago. I didn't figure out a working approach then but I managed to get one now. By the way, yaml/store is pretty cool and you can take credit for introducing me to it.

Anyway, on with the code. Basically here's a couple important concepts:

- The `@store` is similar to a hash in that you can use `[]` and `[]=` but it's not actually a hash, it's a `YAML::Store`.
- Ruby 2.3 has a method [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) which is kind of the missing puzzle piece here. You provide a list of keys and it treats each as successive keys. You can use this for both `get` and `set`, as my code shows
- If `@store` were a true hash that would be the end of it but's not, so for this answer I added a `YAML::Store#dig` method which has the same usage as the original.

---

```
require 'yaml/store'

class YAML::Store
  def dig(*keys)
    first_val = self[keys.shift]
    if keys.empty?
      first_val
    else
      keys.reduce(first_val) do |result, key|
        first_val[key]
      end
    end
  end
end

class YamlStore
  attr_reader :store
  def initialize filename
    @store = YAML::Store.new filename
  end
  def get *keys
    @store.transaction do
      @store.dig *keys
    end
  end
  def set *keys, val
    @store.transaction do
      final_key = keys.pop
      hash_to_set = keys.empty? ? @store : @store.dig(*keys)
      hash_to_set.send :[]=, final_key, val
    end
  end
end

filename = 'store.yml'
db = YamlStore.new filename

db.set :a, {}
puts db.get :a
# => {}

db.set :a, :b, 1
puts db.get :a, :b
# => 1
```

Comment: AWESOME. Dig is exactly the thing I knew I needed but didn't know about. It'l take me some work to digest the code example you provided, but I already see where we're headed and it looks perfect. Thanks so much!